# Динамический сайт на HTML

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

Что означает такая строка:

```
http://news.mail.ru/currency.html?charcode=USD&sputnik=1
```

Немного непонятно, как `HTML`-странице можно передать что-то `GET`-ом. Или `HTML`-страницы тоже умеют обрабатывать скрипты?

Comment: @alex_90 - гет передается не странице а серверу. Из возможного применения, например - можно распарсить эти значения в js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окончание currency.html  вовсе и не значит что это (скорее всего так и есть) как таковая физически созданная страница. Скорее всего мод реврайтом созданная..
Например сервер реально обрабатывает страницу как (например) Флаг [QSA]

```
?page=currency&charcode=USD&sputnik=1

RewriteRule ^currency.html$ index.php?do=currency [QSA]
```

Но и заставить апаче(nginx) обработать страницу хтмл как пхп не намного сложнее (ниже пример для .htaccess

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: Зачем они людей так путают??))

Comment: Нет)) Людям так удобнее смотреть. Для сео полезнее

Comment: Достал этот миф, можно авторитетный пруф?( Не с чьего-то сео бложка )

Answer (score 2):

<p>такой код вполне может быть и для html, если внутри html есть JS, который может обработать эти входные данные.</p>